# String to int function

Tags: python, function

I had the assignment to create a function which would allow the user to input a string of numbers and then receive that string as an int list. I was also supposed to use string slicing for this particular function. That being said I couldn't come up with anything fancy and this is what I wrote:

```
def Split_to_Integers():
    print("Put in a string:")
    Input = str(input())
    List = []
    List.append(Input)
    print(List)
```

It is nothing fancy but it somehow got the job done. However, I also have the official solution which looks as follows:

```
def split_to_integers(inputstr):
    res = []
    last = 0
    max = len(inputstr)
    for i in range(max):
        if inputstr[i] == " ":
            nmbr = inputstr[last:i]
            last = i+1
            res.append(int(nmbr))
nmbr = inputstr[last:]
res.append(int(nmbr))
return res
```

The second function works when I put in one integer, however, as soon as I put in a second one, the function crashes, and I dont know where the Problem is.

Comment: If your input is a series of numbers separated by a space why not splitting the string by spaces? You could something like [int(x) for x in your_input. Split(" ")]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a question-and-answer site, so what's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: That second snippet is not valid. It looks like the last three lines should be indented.

Comment: How does your code "get the job done"? It returns a list containing a single string, not a list of integers.

Comment: Sidenote: `str(input())` is redundant since `input()` returns a `str`.

Comment: What error is the second function giving you? I just tried `split_to_integers('5 6')` and it worked fine -- returned `[5, 6]`. (After fixing the indentation of course.) Please make a [mre] including complete code, example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: In fact, the original code does not even *return* anything useful; it just *prints* the list that contains the input string as the only item...

Comment: Sidenote: avoid *Capitalized_Words_With_Underscores* for function names. [Use *lower_case_with_underscores* instead.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function of strings. Like so:

```py
def list_from_string(number_string: str):
    ints = [int(item) for item in number_string.split(" ")]
    return ints

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = input("Enter the string: ")
    result = list_from_string(s)
    print(result, type(result))
```

This is the behavior in a console:

```
Enter the string: 6 5 4
[6, 5, 4] <class 'list'>
```